# How Can I call startActivityForResult() from activity and get data inside Fragment?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity

I want to choose contact via Intent. But what I want to do is there is button on Activity through I will startActivityOnResult() and want to get that contact inside the fragment available on the same activity. Is there any way I can do this?

**NOTE : I am using ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> because startActivityOnResult() is deprecated.**

I have tried to send data through the interface but My mentor didn't think it is the right way to do so and I can't think any other way I can do that

Comment: The "right" way (the one recommended by Android documentation) is to either write your own contract for ActivityResultLauncher, or to use the generic `StartActivityForResult()` contract. [Their very brief instructions are here.](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#custom) Writing your own contract can be nice for encapsulating the code. You cannot practically communicate between activities using an interface. If the data you need to pass is complex, use Parcelables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you can create public method with param in fragment and access this method in ActivityResultLauncher with the help of fragment instance and pass data to this method. Or you can use LiveData with MVVM.